# Вывести сумму одного столбца за неделю

Tags: php, javascript, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица где каждый день заполняется столбик **"work"** информацией которую нужно в конце недели выводить сумму в столбце **"summa"** . Как правильно прописать код чтоб все корректно показывалось ?

**СТРУКТУРА ТАБЛИЦЫ**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ТАБЛИЦА**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ФУНКЦИОНАЛ**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['dateList'])) {
    $DATE = new DateTime($_POST['dateList']);
} else {
    $DATE = new DateTime('NOW');
}
$DATE->setTime(23, 59, 59);
$DATE_END = clone $DATE;
$DATE_END->modify('-12 month')->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tab_1` WHERE `user-data` >= '".$DATE_END->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' AND `user-data` < '".$DATE->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'";
$sql = mysqli_query($link , $query);

$DATE_NOW = new DateTime('NOW');
for ($x = 0; $x <= $DATE_NOW->format('t'); $x++) {
    echo $x.' - ';
} 


if ($sql !== FALSE)
{
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

        echo      
            '<tr>'.
            '<td>'.$result['name'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['user-data'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['summa'].'</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>'.
            '<td>'.$result['work'].'.ч</td>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Создать триггеры на вставку и обновление записи, которые обновляют сумму у всех записей с той же неделей. А если делать правильно - то выбросить поле `summa` нахрен и считать понедельную сумму запросом.

Comment: Можно пример навести как это делать ?

Comment: Это - пардон, что именно?

Comment: как в моем случае примерно посчитать запросом сумму за неделю .

Comment: В простейшем случае `SELECT YEAR(date), WEEK(date,1), SUM(work) FROM table GROUP BY YEAR(date), WEEK(date,1)`. Плюс корректировка на Новый год, если нужно.

Comment: У меня такое по идее ??   $query = "SELECT *WEEK('user-data') , SUM(work) FROM `tab_1` GROUP BY WEEK('user-data') WHERE `user-data` >= '".$DATE_END->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' AND `user-data` < '".$DATE->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'";